# How to compress my setup file in nsis?

Tags: nsis

I want to compress my setup file in nsis script.I have my original  files which will be bundled using nsis is of size 160mb .I am currently using lzma/solid compression so i am getting a setup file of 58mb.Is there any other way to compress it  more.I want a setup file of 30 mb .Is it possible .
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While NSIS does have some compressor options (`SetCompressorDictSize` for lzma) you are probably not going to get from 58 to 30.

Are you able to do it with 7zip/lzma2 or WinRar?